# Expo start Couldn't adb reverse: adb.exe: error: device offline

Tags: android, expo

For using Expo start react-native project, the adb connection error occurs.
Need to connect the Expo local and Android studio emulator
Console error is something like that.

```
To run the app, choose one of:
› Scan the QR code above with the Expo app (Android) or the Camera app (iOS).
› Press a for Android emulator, or w to run on web.
› Press e to send a link to your phone with email.

Press ? to show a list of all available commands.
Couldn't adb reverse: adb.exe: error: device offline
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: adb.exe: device offline
Couldn't adb reverse: adb.exe: error: device offline
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: adb.exe: device offline
```

Somebody help me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to solve this as follows:

1. Launch the Android Studio emulator
2. Open the Settings app within the emulator
3. Activate developer mode (by tapping the build number repeatedly)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my own case, I simply opened the "AVD Manager" in Android Studio, located the emulator in "virtual devices" and clicked on the three dots I chose "cold boot" and my problem was solved